# Is there a way to have an interactive / editable desktop background (E.g.: A spreadsheet) on a Macbook?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, software-recommendation, ms-office, desktop

The title basically gives the gist of what I am curious about, but to explain more: I wanted to set up a system where I track various things, such as my habits, mood, and tasks every day. I was planning to keep all of this in an Excel spreadsheet. I thought that it would be great if I could make the document where I keep track of this easily visible, so I will remember to edit it every day, and also because it would be easier to access and edit.

Through Googling, I found that at one point in time it was possible to embed an interactive spreadsheet as your desktop wallpaper in Windows. It involved saving the Excel spreadsheet as a webpage (.htm or .html), checking an option called "Add Interactivity", and the document could be set as the desktop background, and it would be editable from there (allegedly). The feature(s) that allowed this in Excel back then don't seem to be available in the 2016 version of Excel for Mac. So, is there a different way to do this now? Or is there some type of desktop Widget I could use as a Spreadsheet? I'm flexible about solutions, so any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Would Dashboard be sufficient?  Based on the question as I see it now, I wouldn't have thought so, but Steve Biro brought it up in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [desktopr](https://www.desktopr.link) and add a link to a Google sheet.

The service allows you to set any website as your wallpaper. Heard about it on Product Hunt.

Comment: This does what I want it to! I like that you can turn up the transparency so the normal background still is easy to see. Overall a nifty app.

Comment: App store says this application is not available in your region. (I am from India).

Answer (score 0):

I made an app for this. It's free and open-source: https://github.com/sindresorhus/Plash It lets you set any website as your desktop wallpaper.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there's anything that directly involves Excel, but you could look in the [Apple Dashboard Widgets store](https://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/). Then again, Apple could be phasing out the Dashboard, considering how tricky it is to enable it in Sierra. Other than that, keeping a small window or a separate desktop open is the only option I'm aware of.